# Por que no se pasa ningun parametro?

Tags: c#, webservice, xamarin, aplicación-web, asp.net-web-api

Estoy trabajando(soy nuevo en xamarin) en XAMARIN
Puedo tomar la foto, adicionar al content, ver el file.FileName,
Pero cuando invoco el WEB API: No se pasa ningun parametro.
Realmente estoy completamente y absolutamente perdido y no se la solucion

```
 private async void TakePhoto_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     var file = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
     var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
     content.Add(new StreamContent(await file.OpenReadAsync()), "file", file.FileName);
     string url = "https://10.0.2.2:7254/api/GetData/Upload/";
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);       
     var response = await client.PostAsync("", content);
     if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           
  }



[HttpPost]
        [Route("Upload")]
        public async Task<string> Upload(  List <IFormFile> files)    
        {
            try
            {

                 foreach (var formFile in files)
                 {
                      if (formFile.Length > 0)
                      {
                         var fileName =  formFile.FileName.Split('\\').LastOrDefault().Split('/').LastOrDefault();
                         var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "imagenes", fileName);
                        
                        using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
                        {
                            await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                        }
                        return " " + fileName;
                      }
                 }

            }
```

Comment: A qué esperas que se le tenga que pasar parámetros? Francamente no comprendo cuál es la pregunta.

Comment: Podríás por favor mostrar el mensaje de error completo o lo que sea que necesites revisar?